# Using tangents to avoid a sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have an eagle travelling with vector equation $\vec E_a = [4,5,7] + t[-0.5,-0.8,1]$ towards a spherical guard radius around another eagle's nest with equation $(x+1)^2 + (y+2)^2 + (z-16)^2 = 4$. The eagle first enters the sphere at $t=7.65$ seconds with coordinates $P(0.175,-1.12,14.65)$ and is subsequently chased and attacked by the guarding eagle.

I want to avoid the guard radius whilst maintaining a similar rate of ascension. My initial idea was to choose another point on the flight path before the collision such as $Q(1.5,1,12)$ which is when $t=5$, and then draw tangent lines to the sides of the sphere and then avoid the sphere by travelling at an angle greater than the angle made between the tangent lines and the initial flight path past $Q$. [Kind of like the tangent lines circle theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE1jP.png).

My problem is that I am not too sure how to determine which points on the sphere I should use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "A similar $z$-level" isn't entirely clear. You want to keep the same rate of ascent (height per time)? Touch the sphere at the same height as $P$ or as $Q$? In any case, you'll probably want to use the fact that a tangent line is always perpendicular to the radius from the sphere's center to the tangent point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Calling

$$
\cases{
p = (x,y,z)'\\
p_0=(-1,-2,-16)',\ \ r = 2\\
q_1=(1.5,1,12)'\\
\vec v = (-0.5,-0.8,1)'\\
\vec u = (u_x,u_y,u_z)'
}
$$

we have that the sphere $\|p-p_0\|^2=r^2$ should be tangentially touched by a line $p = q_1 + \lambda \vec u$ then substituting this line into the sphere

$$
\|q_1+\lambda\vec u-p_0\|^2 = r^2\Rightarrow \|q_1-p_0\|^2+2\lambda(q_1-p_0)\cdot\vec u + \lambda^2\|\vec u\|^2=r^2
$$

solving for $\lambda$

$$
\lambda = \frac{-(q_1-p_0)\cdot\vec u\pm\sqrt{((q_1-p_0)\cdot\vec u)^2-\|\vec u\|^2(\|q_1-p_0\|^2-r^2)}}{\|\vec u\|^2}
$$

as the line and the sphere are tangent

$$
\cases{
((q_1-p_0)\cdot\vec u)^2-\|\vec u\|^2(\|q_1-p_0\|^2-r^2)=0\\
\|\vec u\|^2=1
}
$$

and solving for $u_x, u_y$ we obtain $\vec u = (u_x(u_z),u_y(u_z),u_z)'$

Follows a plot shoving the point $q_1$ in red, and the family $\vec u(u_z)$ in black.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain why ||u||^2 =1?

Comment: To have a normalized vector with unitary length .

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your eagle has reached the point $Q = (1.5, 1, 12)$ at $t = 5$.

Now, your eagle wants to turn slightly so that it approaches the sphere tangentially.  The possible paths from $Q$ to the surface of the sphere obviously form a right circular cone.  Its axis is determined by the vector

$ V = C - Q = (-1, -2, 16) - (1.5, 1, 12) = (-2.5, - 3, 4 ) $

While the semi-vertical angle $\theta$ of the cone (which is defined as the angle between the axis of the cone and its surface) is easy determined by the formula

$ \sin \theta = \dfrac{R}{\| V \| } = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{6.25 + 9 + 16} } = 0.3578 $

From which $ \theta = 20.96^\circ $

To determine the possible directions starting from $Q$ towards the sphere, then, as you mentioned in your post, you would select an angle greater than $\theta$, and change the path of the eagle.

Suppose you choose a larger angle, say $\phi = 25^\circ$, and you want to parameterize all the possible direction with this offset angle $\phi$ from the axis of the cone.

To do that we need to calculate two unit vectors that are: (1) Perpendicular to $V$, and (2) Mutually perpendicular.

Since $V = (-2.5, -3, 4) $

We can take the first perpendicular vector to be

$ u_1 = (3, -2.5 , 0 ) $

And then we take $u_2 = V \times u_1 = ( 10 , 12 , 15.25 ) $

Before we use these two vectors, as mentioned, we have to normalize them, so

$ \hat{u_1} = \dfrac{u_1}{\| u_1 \| } = \dfrac{ (3, -2.5 , 0 ) }{ \sqrt{ 9 + 6.25} } = ( 0.76822, -0.6402, 0) $

and

$ \hat{u_2} = \dfrac{u_2}{\| u_2 \| } = \dfrac{ (10, 12, 15.25) }{ \sqrt{ 10^2 + 12^2 + 15.25^2} } = ( 0.45808, 0.54969,  0.69857 ) $

Now the unit direction vector of the eagle starting from $Q$ is given by

$ u(s) = \hat{V} \cos \phi + \sin \phi \ ( \cos s \ \hat{u_1} + \sin s \ \hat{u_2} ) $

Where $ \hat{V}$ is the unit vector along $V$, i.e.

$ \hat{V} = \dfrac{ V }{ \| V \| } = \dfrac{(-2.5, -3, 4) }{\sqrt{ 31.25} } = (-0.4472136 , -0.53666 , 0.71554) $

The rate of ascent before reaching point $Q$ was $1$ unit / sec.

The speed of the bird before $Q$ is given by $v = \sqrt{(-0.5)^2 + (-0.8)^2 + 1 } = 1.37477$ units / sec.

If the bird maintains its speed at $1.37477$ unit/sec, then we want the $z$ component of $ v u $ to be $1$.

The $z$ component of $v u$ is

$ (v u)_z = v ( \cos \phi \hat{V}_z + \sin \phi \ \sin s \ \hat{u_2}_z  ) $

Hence, we have

$ (v u)_z = 1.37477 ( \cos(25^\circ) \ (0.71554) + \sin(25^\circ) \sin s  \ (0.69857) )  = 1$

It follows that

$ \sin s = 0.267233 $

So that $ s = 15.5^\circ $

And this is all we need to determine the direction of travel for the bird after point $Q$, whilst keeping the same rate of ascent at $1$ unit / sec and keeping its speed unchanged.  Note that this means that, the angle that the initial direction of the bird, which is $(-0.5 , -0.8 , 1 )$, makes with the $xy$ plane, is the same as the angle that the new vector $u$ with $s = 15.5^\circ$, makes with the $xy$ plane.

To check that, compute $u$

$ u = \hat{V} \cos \phi + \sin \phi \ ( \cos s \ \hat{u_1} + \sin s \ \hat{u_2} ) $

I've calculated that (details omitted), and I got

$u = (-0.0407218 , -0.68502, .727396 )$

The angle that $u$ makes with $xy$ plane is

$ \psi_u = 90^\circ - \cos^{-1} 0.727396 = 46.668^\circ$

And the angle that $(-0.5, -0.8, 1)$ makes with the $xy$ plane is

$ \psi_i = 90^\circ - \cos^{-1} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(-0.5)^2 + (-0.8)^2 + 1 } } =  46.668^\circ $

As expected, the two angles are equal.